# System doesn't boot after lazy unmounting the partition that had Xubuntu on it

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu

I was trying to run an fsck on my Xubuntu partition, but I needed it unmounted apparently, so I opened recovery mode and ran this command:

`sudo umount -l /dev/sda5`

Apparently lazy unmounting unmounts even with running processes so I just did that without thinking much about it, since I'm unexperienced with Linux. And everything seemed normal as it unmounted /dev/sda5.

Tried running fsck but it didn't work. Gave up and restarted the PC, and it didn't boot. Just went straight to the BIOS screen after a few seconds. And that's how it is now.

I got an Bootable USB Drive with the Xubuntu Installation ISO to check the files and to try and do something at the terminal, so I discovered all the files are still there, and the Xubuntu partition seems unharmed. Then I tried to fix everything with Boot-Repair, and it asked me to create a BIOS Boot partition with Gparted, so I tried, but it gave an error on Libparted saying

`input output error on read /dev/sda`

And that's where I am now. I have Windows 10 and Xubuntu installed on this system.

Comment: So you already tried applying fsck from the Bootable usb to each partition  /dev/sda\* ? If so there is *a possibility* (not a certainty) that /dev/sda is corrupted beyond repair, or even if fixed by fsck would soon be corrupted again.  I would recommend getting another disk and using the Bootable USB to backup all your personal files from Window and Ubuntu if you haven't already.  You might get some complaints when trying to copy the corrupted files and will have to skip those.  Then you can either continue trying to fix /dev/sda or reinstall windows and ubuntu on a new disk.

Comment: I have not actually, I'll try running fsck on each partition now and will update after I do it.

Comment: Not sure about /dev/sda being corrupted. The Ubuntu partition is, indeed, corrupted. Can't even see the files.

Comment: And with Ubuntu unmounted in the usb, fsck didn't work?  When you say you couldn't read the Ubuntu files, that means you mounted /dev/sda<x> doesn't it?  fsck won't work when the Ubuntu file system  is mounted. --- Again, I will emphasize, if the disk physically failed, e.g., it was not corruption due to a power outage or other forced shutdown, but rather disk physical failure, then you should prepare a new disk because once disks begin to exhibit that behavior it is likely to happen with increasing frequency.

Comment: I ran fsck with the partition unmounted. It said something about the superblock being corrupted. It gave me some options to try and one of them actually worked, but after doing the check, it gave an error at the end